# how to call function on the basis of particular button in node.js express

Tags: html, node.js, express

I want to call function on the basis of which button is clicked.
I have EJS file here Called test.ejs

```
<form>
        <input type="submit" value="Click here 1"></input>
        <input type="submit" value="Click here 2"></input>
        <input type="submit" value="Click here 3"></input>
        <input type="submit" value="Click here 4"></input>
</form>
```

And i have JS file name test.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) { 
console.log("Get the Request from test...!!!");
});
function button1(){
  console.log("User Click Button 1");
}
function button2(){
  console.log("User Click Button 2");
}
function button3(){
  console.log("User Click Button 3");
}
function button4(){
  console.log("User Click Button 4");
}
module.exports = router;
```

I want to call `fuction button1()` when button 1 click similarly with button 2,3 and 4.
What is the procedure. Please help me with some example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use AJAX or WebSockets:

**AJAX:**

(I assume you have jQuery)

html:

```
<button id='button1'> Test </button>
```

js(client):

```
$('#button1').click(function(){
    console.log('button clicked');
    $.ajax({url: 'test1', success:function(res){
        console.log('server response is', res);
    }});
});
```

js(server):

```
function buttonAction1(res){
    res.send('ok');
}
router.get("/test1", function (req, res) {
    buttonAction1(res);
});
```

**WebSockets:**

I prefer using something like [socket.io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io). Here is some [tutorial](http://www.programwitherik.com/socket-io-tutorial-with-node-js-and-express/) you can use.

Comment: Thanks man (http://stackoverflow.com/users/4240685/oleksandr-korzhykov) finally i got what i wanted.  i had to do just lil bit correctionlet say, i wanted to call some other function let fun() in test1.js file.. for invoking that particular function we just have to provide proper path like test1/fun n it worked as all i wanted.. :) thanks..